Unable to get stream in chunks , it returning the whole text in react native
Same code is retuning in chunks in node js. I have done polyfillFetch in react native to support streaming. But it's not sending in chunks, it's sending the complete text after some time. I am using expo for the app
import {
      polyfill,
      polyfill as polyfillFetch,
    } from "react-native-polyfill-globals/src/fetch";
    import "react-native-get-random-values";
    import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto";
    import { ReadableStream } from "web-streams-polyfill";
    import "text-encoding-polyfill";
    
    globalThis.ReadableStream = ReadableStream;
    polyfill();
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
        console.log("fetch");
        const response =  fetch(
          "https://sample.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/",
          {
            reactNative: { textStreaming: true },
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              query: "how are you ?",
            }),
          }
        ).then((response) => response.body)
        .then( async (body) => {
          const reader = body.getReader()
          const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
          while (true) {
            const { value, done } = await reader.read()
            if (done) {
              break
            }
            const decodedChunk = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true })
            console.log(decodedChunk);
          }
        });
    
      };


As far as I know, React native doesnt support ReadableStream. On the readme page react native polyfill global also say that they do not support ReadableStream (here)

@PhantomSpooks it says react native doesn't support it but they do. Actually I checked above code is working. Current issue which I am facing is it doesn't work on Android dev but works in release mode. There's no simple way fix this with expo
